# Python Requests - Hiding 'Max retries exceeded with url'

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests to send a post to an API with proxies however I'm trying to make the console output look clean, not spamming with errors that the proxy 'fails to connect'. Is there a way to hide errors like this one?:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))
```

I set a timeout for as well, nothing seems to be working and my console output is being spammed with that

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: Catch that specific exception and not log it?

Comment: Let's see some code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python urllib3: close idle connection after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345555/python-urllib3-close-idle-connection-after-some-time)

Comment: get the max retires